# Open Refine - Regroup rows values by column values

Tags: openrefine, grel

I am new Open refine user and don't know how to code.

I would like to group multiple values of a column compared to an other column.

I have this file

| ID 1 | ID 2 |
| --- | --- |
| ID1.1 | ID2.1 |
| ID1.1 | ID2.2 |
| ID1.2 | ID2.3 |
| ID1.2 | ID2.4 |
| ID1.2 | ID2.5 |

And i'd like to have this one :

| ID 1 | ID 2 |
| --- | --- |
| ID1.1 | ID2.1;ID2.2 |
| ID1.2 | ID2.3;ID2.4;ID2.5 |

The file got 150k lines and multiple columns

I tried to **Add a new column based** on the first column, but I don't how to group the values of the row1, row2, row3... of the second column based on the value of the first column.

Thank you for any answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Switch to record mode](https://kb.refinepro.com/2012/03/difference-between-record-and-row.html) by using blank down on the column `ID 1`
- Use the following GREL in `ID 2` with `forEach(row.record.cells['ID 2'].value,v,v).join(';')` to join data in the first cell
- Delete the unwanted record by going back to rows mode, and bulk editing row where `ID 1` is blank

Video recording of the steps: https://youtu.be/p6urT-CO76s

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I move the 2 columns at the beging of the file and it worked well. thx for everything

Comment: If the answer works for you, can you accept in in StackOverflow by selecting the checkmark. Thank you

Comment: Done. The video helped. Thx again.